# How to find the minimal amount of ordered pairs for specific counts of elements?

Tags: r, optimization, set, combinatorics

I have around 350 sets of ordered pairs (representing firms). All firms have properties, which I can represent numerically as *(x;y)*, where x is a natural number between 1 and 5 and y is between 6 and 10. So an example of this would be:

- Firm A= *(1;8)*
- Firm B= *(4;6)*
- Firm C=*(2;10)*
- Firm D= *(5;10)*

I need to come up with a way to maximize the use of these pairs in order to achieve a specific sum of different elements. Count of elements:

- 35 of element 10;
- 24 of element 9;
- 27 of element 8;
- 53 of element 7;
- 34 of element 6;
- 36 of element 5;
- 25 of element 4;
- 25 of element 3;
- 31 of element 2;
- 6 of element 1

I know that I cannot find a way to use these ordered pairs in order to fully meet my needs. But how can I use these pairs most optimally?

I have tried to manually start with different elements: first using pairs where the first element is for example 1; counting down the number of elements from 6-10 and then moving on to pairs that include the element 2; once again including 6-10 etc. However this manual method isn't ideal given that I'll never know if there's a better way.

Comment: Can you add some code showing what you have already tried?

Comment: Not clear what you are after indeed. Better to provide am example how you proceed with the ordered pairs.

Comment: You'll have to define trade-offs: you want 123 firms for which you want property 1 to 5. And you want 173 firms with properties 6 to 10. So you'll either have too many with properties 1:5, or too few with properties 6:10.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to define a precise objective  function.  If there is no solution that fulfils all criteria, you'll need to define what counts as a good solution. Perhaps this example helps:

```
## property 1
A <- sample( 1:5, size = 350, replace = TRUE)
## property 2
B <- sample(6:10, size = 350, replace = TRUE)


target <- c(6, 31, 25, 25, 36, 34, 53, 27, 24, 35)

## objective function: a solution is logical vector of
## length 350.  You could compute the average deviation
## from the target, or the largest deviation, .....
dtarget <- function(x, target, A, B) {
    actual <- c(table(A[x]), table(B[x]))
    d <- actual - target
    max(abs(d))
    ## or: sum(abs(d))
    ## or: sum(d*d)
    ## or: .....?
}

## a random solution
x0 <- runif(length(A)) > 0.5
dtarget(x0, target, A, B)
## [1] 52
```

Now we run a Local Search.

```
library("neighbours")
library("NMOF")
nb <- neighbourfun(type = "logical", length = length(A))

sol <- LSopt(dtarget,
             algo = list(x0 = x0,    ## initial solution
                         nI = 5000,  ## iterations
                         neighbour = nb),
             A = A,
             B = B,
             target = target)
dtarget(sol$xbest, target, A, B)
## [1] 6

data.frame(target = target,
           sol = c(table(A[sol$xbest]), table(B[sol$xbest])))
##    target sol
## 1       6  12
## 2      31  37
## 3      25  31
## 4      25  31
## 5      36  39
## 6      34  29
## 7      53  47
## 8      27  22
## 9      24  21
## 10     35  31
```